# Java enable MD2 algorithm programmatically

Tags: java, security

Java 1.7 has disabled the use of the MD2 algorithm due to its weak nature. It is automatically set in the `JAVAHOME/lib/security/java.security` file as follows:

```
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2
```

I'm trying to find a way to re-enable MD2 for one particular instance of the SSLContext, but I cannot seem to do that. I have tried the following:

1. Comment out the `"jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2"` property in `java.security`. But...this will enable MD2 all the time, which I don't want to do
2. In the code, use `Security.setProperty("jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms", "");`
   However, I cannot do that for a single SSLContext instance only - the property that I set remains set and cannot be changed afterwards

Is there any way to do something like this:

```
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("ssl");
/* Enable MD2 here */
SSLContext.setDefault(context);
/* Do stuff here */
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("ssl");
/* Disable MD2 here */
SSLContext.setDefault(context);
```

Thanks.